# Value is being outputted twice in Custom Control in Customizer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-controls

I created a custom control in my `WordPress theme`, its working like it should, the control is for a Slider in the Home Page. Using the `Media Library` multiple images can be added, additional to the image other data can be added per image (a Title, subtitle, etc.)

I put a hidden `input` where i put the data for each "Slide" in JSON format, so i get the `JSON` with `get_option` and decode for the `PHP` part (in the home page).

And well its working like it should no errors so far, but then i was cheching the code in the `front-end`

and i found this:

[image]

a second set of the value of the input, which disappears if i remove `<?php $this->link() ?>` from the input.

Checking it with the dev tools i can see a `=""` at the end of the duplicate like if it were an attribute.

Should i leave it? feels like i am missing something.